# send Array through POST in titanium JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, http-post, titanium

I have an 2 dimensional array and need to send it through POST to a server.

My array loks like this:

```
var array = [[Data1,Data2],[Data1,Data2],[Data1,Data2]];
```

This is how i tray to send the array:

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
    },
        timeout : 30000
    });
    client.open("POST", Ti.App.Properties.getString('MyLink'));
    client.send({
        act : 'SendArray',
        MyArray : array
    });
```

The problem is that the server is not responding right to my request. Is this the correct method to send an array through POST?

Comment: should be right. Do you have access to the server to debug the payload?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to the server

Comment: then you need to figure out of it is accepted like this or needs different headers / type of payload.

Comment: what you can try is set up your own endpoint and POST to there and see if it arrives properly

Answer (score 0):

The Appc documentation states **not** to send array data the way you are trying.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-send

Specifically, it states `To send array data, specify each array element individually as a property of the object.`